# A new formula for gcd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, closed-form, gcd-and-lcm

I have derived following formula for gcd(n,k), where a $n$ is odd positive integer and a $k$ is integer

$$\gcd(n,k)=\frac{n^2} {\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \sec^2(\pi k l/n)}$$

I didn't found this formula anywhere. Is it really new? Is it useful for someone or for something?

Comment: Can you give some background on your derivation or insight into the formula?

Comment: Assuming, the formula actually holds for every such pair of integers , since it has complexity $O(n)$ , it cannot compete with the extended euclidean algorithm determining the gcd much more efficient. It might be an interesting theoretical formula, but with no practical merit. Moreover, the summands in the denominator are in general irrational, so we run into precision issues.

Answer (score 0):

@sato
Let start with this equality
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty f(j)\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\exp \left(-i 2 \pi\ k l j/n \right) =
n \sum_{t=1}^\infty f \left( t \frac n {\gcd(n,k} \right)$$
Using
$$f(j)=\frac {x^j} j $$
we receive
$$\ln \prod_{l=0}^{n-1} \left(1-x \exp(-i 2 \pi\frac{ k l}n)\right) = \gcd(n,k)\ln\left(1-x^{\frac n {\gcd(n,k)}}  
 \right)  {*}$$
where $|x| \leq 1 $ and $x \ne 1 $.
Inserting $x=-1 $ we receive for odd $n$ well known Slavin's formula
$$\gcd(n,k)= \log_2 \prod_{l=0}^{n-1} \left(1+\exp(-i 2 \pi\frac{ k l} n\right) $$

Now we substitute into the equation (*) $x=e^{i \phi} $. After double derivation according $\phi $ we receive

$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \csc^2\left(\frac \phi 2 + \frac {\pi k l} n\right) = \frac {n^2} {\gcd(n,k)} \csc^2\left(\frac {\phi} 2 \frac n {\gcd(n,k)}\right) $$
Inserting $\phi=\pi $ we receive for odd $n$
$$\gcd(n,k)=\frac{n^2} {\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \sec^2(\pi k l/n)}$$